# Quelle est la signification de « pour pendant » ensemble ?

Tags: sens

J'ai lu une phrase que je ne comprends pas du tout :

« L'enthousiasme mystique d'Oikè avait ***pour pendant*** le pragmatisme de Ploos. »

Je ne comprends pas la phrase « pour pendant » puisque lorsque je cherche les mots ensembles les seules choses que je trouve sont des explications pour les différences entre « pour », « pendant », et « durant » lorsqu'on parle de temps.

Ça vient de chapitre 2 de Latium I par Romain Lucazeau. C'est une livre un peu littéraire et je pense qu'il y a des phrases incomplètes. Peut-être c'est une de celles-ci ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« Pour pendant » est la combinaison de « pour », préposition et de « pendant », nom masculin signifiant  familièrement « personne ou chose comparable ou symétrique à une autre » ([TLFi, pendant²](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pendant)).

> P. anal., fam. Personne ou chose comparable ou symétrique à une autre. Synon. contrepartie, répartie, réplique, pareil, semblable.

Comment: J'aurais dû checker [context.reverso.net](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/pour+pendant) !  Merci. Ça l'explique parfaitement.

Comment: @malan Yes, you could very well say "was matched by".

Comment: *Avoir pour pendant* n'est plus du tout aujourd'hui du registre familier mais au contraire plutôt soutenu et littéraire.